# Automatically Dismiss Message Box intReturn = objShell.Popup hangs sometimes

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub auto_click()
' auto_click Macro
' me

Dim row, int_link_cnt, Range As Integer
Dim var As Variant
int_link_cnt = 2

Range = Cells(2, "G").Value
Tmout = Cells(4, "G").Value

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

For row = 2 To Range

Cells(row, "C").Select
On Error Resume Next
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True

Cells(row, "D").Select
Selection.Style = "Good"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "YES"

Cells(row, "E").Select
Selection.Style = "Good"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Now()

On Error Resume Next

'intReturn = objShell.Popup("txt msg", timeout , "title", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

intReturn = objShell.Popup("Timeout 1 sec Yes or NO!", 1, "Next link", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

'intReturn = objShell.Popup("Timeout " & Tmout & " sec Yes or NO!", Tmout, " Next " & int_link_cnt & " link ", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

'intReturn = objShell.Popup("Timeout " & Tmout & " sec Yes or NO!", Tmout, " Next " & int_link_cnt & " link ")

On Error Resume Next

int_link_cnt = 1 + int_link_cnt

If (intReturn = vbYes) Then
GoTo nextLink
End If

If (intReturn = vbNo) Then
GoTo kill
End If


nextLink:
Next row
kill:
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this [tag:vbscript] or more likely [tag:vba]? VBScript doesn’t support the `As` operator in variable declarations so it must be VBA, VB or something similar that bases itself on one of these

Comment: Your code has numerous issues. Please post your code as code (using the code feature of the edit box) and not as HTML. Why all the `On Error Resume Next`? That functions as `On Error Hide Bug`. Note that `Dim row, int_link_cnt, Range As Integer` only declares the last variable as an `Integer` -- the others are Variants. Using `Range` as a variable name is a bad idea since `Range` has a built-in meaning in Excel VBA. `GoTo` is not considered a good control flow mechanism. Finally, what does `Popup` give you that the VBA `Msgbox` doesn't?